# 1005 - Can't create table '' errno: 150

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, innodb

Estou começando minha jornada em programação e me deparei com um erro
na criação do banco MySQL:

> ## 1005 - Can't create table 'mydb.fornecedor' (errno: 150)

O que será? Já entrei em vários fóruns mas essa mesma mensagem de erro aparece para vários tipos de erros no MySQL e ainda não consegui identificar o erro que esta sendo apresentando.

O script:

```
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`fornecedor`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`fornecedor` (
  `id_fornecedor` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `id_observ_fornecedor` INT NOT NULL ,
  `nome_fan` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `razao_social` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `cnpj` CHAR(15) NULL ,
  `fone1` CHAR(11) NULL ,
  `fone2` CHAR(11) NULL ,
  `fone3` CHAR(11) NULL ,
  `fone4` CHAR(11) NULL ,
  `email1` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `email2` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `email3` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `endereco` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `ramo_atuacao` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `forn_desd` DATE NULL ,
  `criado_por` INT NULL ,
  `criado_data` DATETIME NULL ,
  `alterado_por` INT NULL ,
  `alterado_data` DATETIME NULL ,
  `deletado_por` INT NULL ,
  `deletado_data` DATETIME NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_fornecedor`, `id_observ_fornecedor`) ,
  INDEX `fornecedor_id_observ_idx` (`id_observ_fornecedor` ASC) ,
  INDEX `fk_fornecedor_lista_cot_forn` (`id_fornecedor` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_id_observ`
    FOREIGN KEY (`id_observ_fornecedor` )
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`observ` (`id_observ` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_fornecedor_lista_cot_forn`
    FOREIGN KEY (`id_fornecedor` )
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`lista_cot_forn` (`id_fornecedor_lista_cot_forn` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: você também pode criar a tabela sem as constraints primeiramente, e tentar adicionar elas posteriormente. Assim saberia exatamente qual está disparando o erro.

Answer (score 6):

Este erro é referente à `constraints`. Verifique se as relações definidas no seu script já existem e se são todas válidas...

```
  INDEX `fornecedor_id_observ_idx` (`id_observ_fornecedor` ASC) ,
  INDEX `fk_fornecedor_lista_cot_forn` (`id_fornecedor` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_id_observ`
    FOREIGN KEY (`id_observ_fornecedor` )
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`observ` (`id_observ` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_fornecedor_lista_cot_forn`
    FOREIGN KEY (`id_fornecedor` )
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`lista_cot_forn` (`id_fornecedor_lista_cot_forn` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Se você tentar criar uma relação obrigatória com outra tabela, e aquela tabela não existir seguindo estas definições, você não irá conseguir criar sua tabela.

Além das tabelas existirem com a estrutura esperada, é necessário que os dados da outra tabela também atendam as expectativas.

Comment: a mensagem de erro referente à constraints é o (errno 121), muito obrigado,eu entendi o que você quis dizer, mas depois de ter feito essas alterações o erro continua

Comment: o que eu quis dizer é que esse erro pode ser indiretamente relacionado com alterações em contraints em tabelas já populadas.

eu faria um teste com uma base vazia pra tentar entender se existe alguma relação...

Answer (score 2):

A resposta do Guilherme está certa. Quando escrevo scripts assim para criar tabelas, ponho antes de tudo as tabelas 'pais', para depois escrever as tabelas filhas. Assim sendo, o script não dará esses erros comuns, pois as tabelas e todas as referências e colunas serão disponível.

**Tabela Pai**

A tabela pai é a tabela que servirá como *referência* em outra tabela. No seu caso, `mydb.observ` é uma tabela pai para a tabela `fornecedor`.

**Tabela Filha**

A tabela filha é a tabela que *tem as referências*, ou seja, que se refere *às outras tabelas*. No seu caso, a tabela `fornecedor` é a tabela filha para ambas `observ` e `lista_cot_forn`.

NOTE: Uma tabela pode ser pai de uma tabela e filha de outra. Qualquer `RDBMS` (relational dabaste management system, como Oracle, MySQL, ou SQL Server) tem essa mesma teoria.

Comment: Erros com foreign keys também são comuns quando você resolve adicionar uma constraint a um campo que já existente em uma tabela...

Comment: Valeu melque_tcd pela ajudinha no português :)

Comment: Sempre tenho esse erro, e pra mim é um erro do próprio mysql, ou melhor dos utilitários que fazem dump, o minimo esperado é que o utilitário "cheque" isso e faça o dump na ordem correta.